# How do I scrape data from within an HTML element based on an existing URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, rss, rss-reader

I have a script to save RSS data into a Spreadsheet, but it still has shortcomings and problems.

I have received data in the form of
**title, time, article link.**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YTAF.png

I want the script to be able to retrieve descriptions based on tags or HTML classes from each article link, so that the data I get is **title, time, description, article link**

For example, I want to retrieve the **description** of a div class called **entry-content** from the article link https://e-ficiencia.com/samsung-climate-solutions-acudira-cyr-2023/

My hope is that the data I get on the Spreadsheet will be like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT00s.png
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPn7xHEEI1NknN8l9w6hu4SkQburm8s-NdAjPsPc-NM/edit#gid=0

Following my Google Apps Script

```
function myFunction() {
  getURLData();
}

function getURLData() {
 
  var currentData = [];
  var urltoCheck = ["https://e-ficiencia.com/feed/", "https://www.climanoticias.com/feed/all","https://www.proinstalaciones.com/actualidad/noticias?format=feed"];
  for (var i = 0; i < urltoCheck.length; i++){
  var ficiencaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urltoCheck[i]);
  var xml = ficiencaData.getContentText()
  let response = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = response.getRootElement();
   let channel = root.getChild('channel');
  let items = channel.getChildren('item');
    items.forEach(item => {
      let title = item.getChild('title').getText();
      let pubDateb = item.getChild('pubDate').getText();
      let link = item.getChild('link').getText();
      currentData.push([title,pubDateb,link])
   
  });
}
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var currentDataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, currentData.length, currentData[0].length);
  currentDataRange.setValues(currentData); 
  
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot open your provided Spreadsheet to confirm `My hope is that the data I get on the Spreadsheet will be like this`. Can you confirm it again? And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `For example, I want to retrieve the description of a div class called entry-content from the article link https://e-ficiencia.com/samsung-climate-solutions-acudira-cyr-2023/`, I cannot understand your expected value. Can I ask you about your expected value?

Comment: @Tanaike https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT00s.png

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `Your answer is not wrong, but it doesn't meet my expectations.`, I understood that my understanding of your question was not correct. In this case, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Sorry I have troubled and disappointed you, I hope you are not offended by my previous reply

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I am trying to retrieve your expected values. But, unfortunately, it seems that the xpath of your expected values are not constant. By this, in order to retrieve your expected values, it is required to prepare all xpaths for all values. And, the xpath might be changed in the future update. From this situation, I am trying to look for a method for retrieving your expected values in a simple way. So, it will help me when you can give me time to do it. I deeply apologize that I cannot propose an answer soon because of my poor skill.